# Zend: best way to implement custom form validation?

Tags: php

I have a few custom form validation rules I wish to apply. Things like ensuring the password has one capital letter, at least one number, and a symbol.

Where would be best to implement these custom validation rules?

I am currently validating them in a controller, but obviously that won't scale very well when I expand. So I was going to implement them as view helpers.

I don't have too much experience with zend_form. Is there a way to set a custom validation handler when constructing the form object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't have too much experience with
>   zend_form. Is there a way to set a
>   custom validation handler when
>   constructing the form object?

Yes when constructing the form you can add a set of validators to any form field you wish. I like to make individual Fomr classes that extend Zend_Form... and here i set the default configuration for that form. If something need to be different in a specific usage then i override as necessary in the controller.

[Check out the manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.elements.html) and update your question or start a new one ith specific issues you run in to.

Comment: Thanks! I am also new to stackoverflow. I see this is less like a forum for stupid questions.

Was just reading the manual then. Will update my question with something more specific should I have further trouble.

Comment: It's also possible (and often advisable) to push your validation (via Zend_Form) down into your model layer:  http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/200-Using-Zend_Form-in-Your-Models.html

Comment: The only problem with that is what if I want to set custom validation errors and I don't use zend_form to do so. Suddenly, I am defining these error messages within a model, which to me, does not seem like it belongs there.

Comment: you would simply add method to change the validation messages on the form instance via accessors on the form and/or model - granted ive never don this with ZF as anything that would denote a need for theis level of complexity i would be using Symfony for instead of ZF. That said Symfony uses a similar validation system to what Matthews post suggest - its just more robust and more tightly coupled.